# Install macOS Monterey on MacBook Pro M2 Max (2023)

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

I just bought the new MacBook Pro M2 Max and I need to have macOS Monterey installed in order to use it as my work machine.

Before buying the Mac I called Apple to know if this new MacBook Pro (m2 Max) is compatible with Monterey and they told me that “yes, it is the case.”

But, when I try to install macOS Monterey from the App Store I'm getting a message that “no version is compatible with my machine.”

I saw a page on Apple’s website listing the machines compatible with Monterey and the new MacBook Pro is not listed but the page is dating from November 2022.

Does what I want to do is possible? If yes, could someone tell me how to process please?

Comment: It would be very unusual for an Apple machine to be able to run an OS befoire the one it was manufactured with. You could run Monterey in a VM e.g. UTM. (or my view is if it is used for work then work should supply it and use your own computer for your own use)

Comment: If your requirement is for a Monterey machine, you should look at one of the M1Pro/M1Max that are available at excellent prices.

Comment: According to [everymac.com](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/index-macbookpro.html), no MacBook Pro models with a M2 Max processor are compatible with macOS Monterey.

Comment: Given that you specified Monterey as a requirement, you should return the Mac and get an M1 based Mac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I‘m surprised Apple told you this. Monterey lacks the device drivers required for hardware released after it got replaced by Ventura, so I don‘t see how this could work.

You might be able to run Monterey in a VM.

Comment: @Ferdi777 Try grabbing one of the Monterey IPSW's and a copy of UTM and run that.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I will give a try :)

Comment: @Ferdi777 have you been able to try with UTM or Parallels ? I am considering purchasing a MacBook Pro M2 Max, but if i cannot run a Monterey VM that could be an issue :)